# python app function error when reading a parquet file

Tags: python, azure-functions, parquet

I am developing a python script that will run as a azure app function.
It should read a parquet file from our gen1 datalake and do some processing over it.
When running in debug mode in VS Code it works perfectly but when I deploy the script to the app function it retrieve a error with a not very meaninfull message.

Executed 'Functions.get_warehouse_from_sap' (Failed, Id=227a48b8-0486-4c3f-8758-1f6298afaf68, Duration=9122ms)

This happens when it tries to read the parquet file. I tried to use pyarrow and pandas.read_parquet function but both give the same error. I tried to put a try/execept around this particular point of the code but any excepetion is retrieved. To read the datalake I am using AzureDLFileSystem from azure.datalake.store.core python libray. Here is part of my code.

```
 from azure.datalake.store import lib
 from azure.datalake.store.core import AzureDLFileSystem
 import pandas as pd
    
 adlCreds = lib.auth(tenant_id=tenant_id,
                                client_id=client_id,
                                client_secret=secret_key,
                                resource = 'https://datalake.azure.net/')
 adlsFileSystemClient = AzureDLFileSystem(adlCreds, store_name='<repository name>')
    
 f=adlsFileSystemClient.ls('<path to my file>')
 #until here it works fine. It can open the file
 #here is where the problem happens.
 try:
     df=pd.read_parquet(f)
 except Exception as e:
     logging.info(str(e))
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Well, the `.ls`function will list all the file in the folder. Instead of that I will suggest that you download the file and then read the file.
- To this you will need to run the following code.

```
multithread.ADLDownloader(adlsFileSystemClient,lpath="< Local Path >",rpath="<Path to file>")
```

- Also, while reading the file you need an engine for parquet, we can use `pyarrow` or we can use `fastparquet` for this the code will look like this:

```
pandas.read_parquet("<path of the file>",engine="pyarrow")
```

[image]

Refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-python#download-a-file) on Datalake gen1 .

Comment: Hi Mohit. Thanks for the answer but this doesn't make to much sense for me. Why should I download the file to a local path? Remember that my problem is running the script on the azure app function. Where the local path would be in the case of running the script as a app function?

Comment: Well I just  provided an alternative you can give relative path in azure functions every peice of code will be in a wwwroot folder in function

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to solve the problem. The problem was memory consumption. As I am still running the app in a dev enviroment it has just 1.5Gb of memory. I was reading the whole parquet file which was consuming approximatelly 2.5Gb. I changed my code so I use the pyarrow.read_table with filter option and reading just the necessary columns from the parquet file. This reduced the memory consumption and the app function started working.